# How to append new data to a list View inside a Fragment?

Tags: android

So I've two fragments. One that posts data and one that shows the data in the activity.

So, once the post is done, I don't want to reload the entire Fragment, call the server, get all the data and show it. I just want to append the new piece of data to the fragment. How do I manage that?

Example: Twitter Direct Messages. When I send a direct Message, I don't have to load the entire list of Messages but just append the new message that I sent in the list View. How do I do that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the new data in the data structure you are passing to your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the list view. It will refresh to show the new data.

Comment: The issue here is I am not using an Adapter. I am using a custom view.

Comment: Will have to take a look at your view then